# Function isloggedin in react dont works

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting to learn and practice in React, my idea was to make a login screen, where I call a rest api and store the user in memory, when logging I redirect the user to a Home. The problem is that I want that if the user is logged in, should not be able to look the login screen. To do this, I send the "isLogged" state to the "login" component and if the user has the "Logged" state I want to redirect it. The problem is that the state is not getting correctly:

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import Login from './Pages/Login/Login'
import Logout from './Pages/Logout/Logout'
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home'


export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: "no-logueado",
      user:{},
    };

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
    this.loggedIn = this.loggedIn.bind(this);  

  }

  handleLogin(data){
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: "Logueado",
      user: data
    });
  }

  handleLogout(){
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: "no-logueado",
      user: {}
    });
  }

  isLoggedin(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
    if(this.state.loggedIn === "no-logueado" && token){
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: "Logueado",
        user: token
      });
    }
  }

  loggedIn(data){
    if(data === "Logueado"){
      window.location="/home";
    }
  }

async componentDidMount(){
  await this.isLoggedin();
}

  render() {
    
      return (
        <Router>
          <Route exact path="/" render={props => ( <Login {... props} handleLogin={this.handleLogin} loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}/>)} />
          <Route exact path="/logout" render={props => ( <Logout {... props} handleLogout={this.handleLogout}/>)} />
          <Route exact path="/home" render={props => (<Home {... props} loggedIn={this.loggedIn} log={this.state.loggedIn}/>)} />


          <script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

          <script
            src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
            crossorigin></script>

          <script
            src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
            crossorigin></script>

          <script>var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;</script>
        </Router>
      );
  }
}
```

Login

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Input from './Components/Input/input'
import Label from './Components/Label/Label'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './Login.css'
import {Container, Row, Col, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user:' ',
            password:' '
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleSuccessfullAuth = this.handleSuccessfullAuth.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(name, value) {
        if(name==='username'){
            this.setState({user:value});
        } else {
            this.setState({password:value});
        }
    }

    async handleSubmit(){

            const requestOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    body: JSON.stringify({ 
                        email: this.state.user,
                        password:this.state.password
                    })
            };
            
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', requestOptions);
            console.log(response.ok);
            if(response.ok){
                const res = await response.json();
                localStorage.setItem("authToken", res.token)
                this.handleSuccessfullAuth(res);
            } else {
                console.log("token", localStorage.getItem("authToken"))
            }
             
        }

        handleSuccessfullAuth(data){
            this.props.handleLogin(data);
            this.props.history.push("/home");
        }
    
        componentDidMount(){
            console.log(this.props.loggedIn)
        }

    render(){
        return (       
            <div id="login-background">
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={6}>
                            <Col xs={8}  className="back">
                                <h2 className="tittle-login">¡ Bienvenido !</h2>
                                <h2 className="tittle-login">{this.props.loggedIn}</h2>
                                <hr className="hr-design"></hr>
                            <Label text='Usuario'/>
                            <Input attribute= {{
                                id: 'username',
                                name:'username',
                                type:'text',
                                placeholder:'Ingrese su usuario ...',
                                className:'form-control'
                            }}
                            handleChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                            <Label text='Contraseña'/>
                            <Input attribute= {{
                                id: 'password',
                                name:'password',
                                type:'password',
                                placeholder:'Ingrese su contraseña ...',
                                className:'form-control'
                            }}
                            handleChange={this.handleChange}
                            /><br></br>
                            <Button variant="primary" size="lg" block onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Iniciar Sesión</Button>{' '}
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={4}>

                            </Col>
                                
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                        
                        </Col>
                            
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When I see through the console how the status reaches "login" it arrives as "not logged in" although the screen renders me "logged in".

I think i need to learn something first or i missed something, could you help me ?

[Render "Logueado" but in console i obtain an "No-logueado" status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t42OE.png)

Home

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Menu from '../../Components/Menu'


export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Menu/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the Home component as well?

Comment: Yes, but i dont have anything in there ... 

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Menu from '../../Components/Menu'


export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Menu/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

I forget something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Redirect` component from `'react-router-dom'` to redirect from the login page to the home page if the user is logged in.

Just add a conditional return inside the `render()` function.

```js
  render() {
    if (this.props.loggedIn === STATE_LOGGED_IN) {
      return <Redirect path="/home" />;
    }

    return (
      <div id="login-background">
        <Container>
    ...
```

I also took the liberty to refactor your components a bit. I have a few suggestions for you.

#### Arrow function

First, you can use arrow functions instead of class methods that require binding. Arrow functions have no `this` keyword, and therefore do not require binding.

```js
  handleLogin = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: STATE_LOGGED_IN,
      user: data,
    });
  };
```

#### Route Children

Secondly, I advise you to use the `children` form of `<Route>` rendering. It's much cleaner and easier to read.

```js
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Login handleLogin={this.handleLogin} loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/logout">
          <Logout handleLogout={this.handleLogout} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <Home loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
```

#### Don't manipulate window.location

You will also notice that I removed the function that called `window.location="/home"`. I advise you to use `react-router-dom` for any changes to location, instead of directly modifying `window.location`.

#### Use const strings

Finally, I advise you to const strings for your `'Logueado'` and `'no-logueado'` strings. By using a const, you avoid the problem of mis-typing the string.

```js
export const STATE_LOGGED_IN = 'Logueado';
export const STATE_LOGGED_OUT = 'no-logueado';
```

#### App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Login from './Pages/Login/Login';
import Logout from './Pages/Logout/Logout';
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home';

export const STATE_LOGGED_IN = 'Logueado';
export const STATE_LOGGED_OUT = 'no-logueado';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: STATE_LOGGED_OUT,
      user: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.isLoggedin();
  }

  handleLogin = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: STATE_LOGGED_IN,
      user: data,
    });
  };

  handleLogout = () => {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: STATE_LOGGED_OUT,
      user: {},
    });
  };

  isLoggedin = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
    if (this.state.loggedIn === STATE_LOGGED_OUT && token) {
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: STATE_LOGGED_IN,
        user: token,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Login handleLogin={this.handleLogin} loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/logout">
          <Logout handleLogout={this.handleLogout} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <Home loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Login.js

Notice the conditional return in the render method.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from './Components/Input/input';
import Label from './Components/Label/Label';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './Login.css';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { STATE_LOGGED_IN, STATE_LOGGED_OUT } from '../../App';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: ' ',
      password: ' ',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.loggedIn);
  }

  handleChange = (name, value) => {
    if (name === 'username') {
      this.setState({ user: value });
    } else {
      this.setState({ password: value });
    }
  }

  async handleSubmit = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.user,
        password: this.state.password,
      }),
    };

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', requestOptions);
    console.log(response.ok);
    if (response.ok) {
      const res = await response.json();
      localStorage.setItem('authToken', res.token);
      this.handleSuccessfullAuth(res);
    } else {
      console.log('token', localStorage.getItem('authToken'));
    }
  }

  handleSuccessfullAuth = (data) => {
    this.props.handleLogin(data);
    this.props.history.push('/home');
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.loggedIn === STATE_LOGGED_IN) {
      return <Redirect path="/home" />;
    }

    return (
      <div id="login-background">
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={6}>
              <Col xs={8} className="back">
                <h2 className="tittle-login">¡ Bienvenido !</h2>
                <h2 className="tittle-login">{this.props.loggedIn}</h2>
                <hr className="hr-design"></hr>
                <Label text="Usuario" />
                <Input
                  attribute={{
                    id: 'username',
                    name: 'username',
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Ingrese su usuario ...',
                    className: 'form-control',
                  }}
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <Label text="Contraseña" />
                <Input
                  attribute={{
                    id: 'password',
                    name: 'password',
                    type: 'password',
                    placeholder: 'Ingrese su contraseña ...',
                    className: 'form-control',
                  }}
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <br></br>
                <Button variant="primary" size="lg" block onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                  Iniciar Sesión
                </Button>{' '}
              </Col>
              <Col xs={4}></Col>
            </Col>
            <Col></Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answers and suggestions.  You help me a lot, im gong to take a look about all yours suggestions